# What command line to use to set up Double Commander's "Run in terminal" feature to use XFCE terminal?

Tags: terminal, xfce, file-manager

Double Commander has a handy "Run in terminal" feature but it is configured to uses xterm by default. Needless to say many prefer to use their desktop environment native terminal client and so do I. The feature is configurable and the default command line to call the terminal application is

```
xterm -e sh -c
```

what to replae it with to use XFCE terminal?

[image: Double Commander behaviour configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Just `xfce4-terminal -e %f` is fine,

But beware if your command dies or quits quickly, you'll see screen flashing.

i.e `xfce4-terminal -e /bin/ls`

P.S Also change the "Run in Terminal" line to `xfce4-terminal` if needed

Comment: `xfce4-terminal -e` says "Failed to execute... no such file or directory". Plain `xfce4-terminal` does nothing at all. And I would like the terminal to remain opened when the application returns.

Comment: @Ivan updated, see if the new answer work for you

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for quite a while and came to a working solutions for *Guake Terminal*, which should be quite familiar to any other:

Run in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/guake -t -n 1 -e
```

Run terminal and open certain path:

```
/usr/bin/guake -t -n 1 -e "cd ""%d"
```

This part `"cd ""%d"`  was the hardest to come up with.